# Consulta y Mostrar información php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo estas dos tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una de ellas muestra usuarios y sus preferencias de OS y la otra muestra consejos y a que OS pertenece.
Quiero hacer una consulta para seleccionar todas las noticias que sean de las preferencias del usuario activo y luego mostrarlas, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer eso.
Había pensado a hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
$ios = $_REQUEST['ios'];
  $android = $_REQUEST['android'];
  $linux = $_REQUEST['linux'];
  $macos = $_REQUEST['macos'];
  $windows = $_REQUEST['windows'];

  if ($ios = 1) {
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM consejos WHERE c_ios='"1"'";
  } elseif ($android = 1) {
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM consejos WHERE c_android='"1"'";
  } elseif ($macos = 1) {
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM consejos WHERE c_macos='"1"'";
  } elseif ($linux = 1){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM consejos WHERE c_linux='"1"'";
  } elseif ($windows = 1) {
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM consejos WHERE c_windows='"1"'";
  }
```

Esta idea no creo que vaya por buen camino, si me podéis ayudar os lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo el siguiente ejemplo, asumiendo que tenemos ambas tablas relacionadas.

Yo en el ejemplo tengo una tabla usuarios y una tabla publicaciones; de la tabla publicaciones yo quiero obtener todos los titulos que pertenecen a un usuario especifico por su id y además si su status como usuarios es activo; entonces mi consultas queda con un JOIN del siguiente modo

```
SELECT titulo, usuario FROM publicaciones
JOIN usuarios
ON usuarios.id = publicaciones.id_usuario
WHERE usuarios.status_usuario = 'activo' AND usuarios.id = 1;
```

Ahora si tus tablas no estan relacionadas, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la sentencia de UNION que unirá 2 tablas aunque no tengan relación; te dejo un ejemplo

```
SELECT user FROM users
WHERE users.id=1
UNION
SELECT title FROM posts
WHERE title = 'primer posts'
ORDER BY title;
```

Solo será cuestión de que lo revises y adaptes a tus necesidades y a la propia estructura de tu tabla

Comment: Las tablas no están relacionadas, no sé si haría falta... De hecho no sabría como hacerlo 

Comment: es parte de tus requisitos que no esten relacionadas? o por que no estan relacionadas?

Comment: opino salvo y aclaro salvo que así lo requiera tu propio desarrollo si revises si las tablas necesitan estar relacionadas

Answer (score 1):

Aclaro un poco: la tabla no está relacionada por que no se exactamente cómo hacerlo y no lo vi necesario.
Una ejemplo para entender lo que quiero hacer sería que cuando un usuario elija android e ios como OS de preferencia se les mostrarán noticias de android e ios.